# How to use ref on two components that are neither child nor parent

Tags: reactjs

The usual way is to create `const ref = React.createRef()` and then
 pass `ref` and `forwardRef()` to component BoxB. But how to pass a `ref` when BoxB is not rendered inside BoxA?

```
class BoxA extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div> content </div>
    )
  }
}


class BoxB extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div> images </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't set `ref`s that way, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I’m trying to remove some styles out from BoxA when there is an event in BoxB. But turns out Box B is not rendered or called inside BoxA Component.

Comment: If these components are siblings, you could rely on parent state, otherwise, context would be a good choice

Comment: They should either interact through common parent or use global state (context, Redux, etc).

Comment: they are not siblings. More of a grandchildren. And their common parent exports all the child components.